# Adding a widget to the "Customer Info" backend page

Tags: php, magento

I am making an internal Magento extension where I would like to add a few key figures to the customer overview, i.e. the `/admin/customer/edit/id/XXX` page:

[image: magento]

How can that be achieved? I've tried looking in the knowledge base, etc. but the documentation on creating extensions seems to be quite limited.

The Magento version is 1.6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to start a module is with [the module creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html). One of the files it adds will be [a config](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config) and to that add the following...

```
<config>
    <!-- ...existing XML here... -->
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <your_module_name>
                    <file>yourmodule.xml</file>
                </your_module_name>
            </update>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

That will cause the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourmodule.xml` to be loaded, to which you can add a single instruction...

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tab_view">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" template="your/module/customer/view.phtml" name="your_module_view" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

And *that* will add (last part, I promise) a block to the customer edit page below the existing sections. It will show the contents of `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/your/module/customer/view.phtml` which you must create and fill with HTML, perhaps a bit like this...

```
<!-- Display a nice header around a box -->
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head"><h4><?php echo $this->__('Your Module Info') ?></h4></div>
    <fieldset>
        Your information will show here.
    </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way is safe, no upgrades can overwrite your additions because all the file paths will have your module name somewhere in them.

Comment: How can I access the customer ID from within that template?

Comment: You can get the customer object directly with `Mage::registry('current_customer')` and from there all of it's attributes.

Comment: Does the same principle apply if I want to add a block to the Admin Dashboard? If so, how would my config file look?

Comment: The same principles apply, you just need to find where to hook your new block. The config file is fine as is, you will need to specify a block in the layout file and of course that means a new template file to use. If you run into a specific problem then start a new question.