# Magento Customer edit - Ajax called twice

Tags: php, ajax, magento, prototypejs

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463041/adding-a-widget-to-the-customer-info-backend-page) I have an other question.

My view looks something like this:

```
<span id="tickets">?</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("greenspan_tickets/index", array('customer_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))); ?>';

function getTicketInfo(){
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'get',
        onComplete: function(transport) {
            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
            document.getElementById('tickets').innerHtml = json.ticket_count;
            alert(document.getElementById('tickets').innerHtml);
        }
    });
}
getTicketInfo();
</script>
```

The user is alerted twice with the correct value of "1" (the correct value from the JSON response). However, to the user the value of #tickets is **still** just "?".

What have I done wrong?

The reason might be this: During the page load the page itself is of course loaded - the URL is something along the lines of `/index.php/admin/customer/edit/id/1/key/7a13c7d7c2feecc16003c82bbf0f6201/`. If I look at Firebug or similar I see that the same request is fired once more, so that in total the same request is done twice:
[image: double-loading]
[see full image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUNII.png)

Can you explain what is wrong? I tried with another production shop that I am running and that also caused double loading of the page.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend not placing the javscript `url` variable in the global scope, rather to define it inside of the `getTicketInfo` function. Its dangerous to put any variables in the global scope, especially ones with such generic names such as `url` because other sloppily written javascript on the page might overwrite it.

Comment: Another note, in Prototype there's a shortcut to `document.getElementById()` which is `$()`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem when the document loads, rather call the AJAX in a on-load event

```
var url = '<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("greenspan_tickets/index", array('customer_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))); ?>';

 function getTicketInfo() {
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
      method: 'get',
      onComplete: function(transport) {
          var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
          document.getElementById('tickets').innerHtml = json.ticket_count;
          alert(document.getElementById('tickets').innerHtml);
      }
    });
 }

 document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
     getTicketInfo();
 });
```

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it didn't make a difference. The function is still called twice and the #tickets innerHtml is not updated on the screen.